# How to join two tables from two different databases?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have this LINQ query that performs a join between two databases (`oContext` and `oCommonContext`):

```
        Logs = from h in oContext.TbHistoryLog
               join o in oCommonContext.TbObjects on h.FormName equals o.ObjectRealName
               join u in oCommonContext.TbUsers on h.UserId equals u.UserId
               where userIds.Contains((Guid)h.UserId) && formNames.Contains(o.ObjectRealName)
               && h.DateUpdated > fromDate && h.DateUpdated < toDate
               orderby h.DateUpdated
               select new HistoryLog
               {
                   Id = h.Id,
                   ObjectId = h.ObjectId,
                   UserName = Helper.CurrLang == Helper.SystemLanguage.Arabic ? u.UserAName : u.UserEName,
                   UserCode = u.UserCode,
                   DateUpdated = h.DateUpdated,
                   ObjectCode = h.ObjectCode,
                   FormName = h.FormName,
                   ObjectName = Helper.CurrLang == Helper.SystemLanguage.Arabic ? o.ObjectAName : o.ObjectEName,
                   State = h.State
               };

        return Logs.ToList();
```

But when I run it, it throws an error:

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts.

I understood that it's not allowed to reference two databases in one query,

I tried this as a workaround:

```
    var histories = oContext.TbHistoryLog.ToList();

    Logs = from h in histories.AsQueryable()
           join o in oCommonContext.TbObjects on h.FormName equals o.ObjectRealName
           join u in oCommonContext.TbUsers on h.UserId equals u.UserId
           where userIds.Contains((Guid)h.UserId) && formNames.Contains(o.ObjectRealName)
           && h.DateUpdated > fromDate && h.DateUpdated < toDate
           orderby h.DateUpdated
           select new HistoryLog
           {
               Id = h.Id,
               ObjectId = h.ObjectId,
               UserName = Helper.CurrLang == Helper.SystemLanguage.Arabic ? u.UserAName : u.UserEName,
               UserCode = u.UserCode,
               DateUpdated = h.DateUpdated,
               ObjectCode = h.ObjectCode,
               FormName = h.FormName,
               ObjectName = Helper.CurrLang == Helper.SystemLanguage.Arabic ? o.ObjectAName : o.ObjectEName,
               State = h.State
           };

    return Logs.ToList();
```

and a different exception is thrown:

> This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your code.

currently it seems I have no options in code, and I think that it's better to create view in SQL, but the problem is that the databases names are unknown and they differ based on the client preferences, so if I made the view in the first database, I don't know the name of the second database, and vice versa.

Comment: `AsQueryable()` is not at all required in `histories.AsQueryable()`. When working with different contexts at least one context data has to be in memory.

Comment: There might be better ways but if the two databases are on the same instance, you can create a view that queries the table in the other database (it is possible also with remote instances). Then you can simply use the view in EF.

Comment: you've got 2 options.  if you want to use 2 contexts, then you have to bring back all the data in memory and do your join there.  or create a synonym in sql server to the remote table and add an entity to the synony in your ef context.